# AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'words'. Doc2Vec error

Tags: model, nltk, gensim, attributeerror, doc2vec

I am trying to train a Doc2Vec word embedding on preprocessed paragraphs. I have removed punctuation, and have carried out tokenization, pos tag and chunking.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec

ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent_pun)))

model = Doc2Vec(ne_tree)
```

I get the error "AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'words'" when I run the Doc2Vec model. What should be done to correct this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Gensim `Doc2Vec` needs the corpus of texts you provide to be an iterable sequence of objects that each have a `words` property (list of string tokens) and `tags` property (list of tag names, usually string tokens).

The example class `TaggedDocument` in gensim is an example of a suitable kind of object. It's apparent that `ne_chunk()` is not returning `TaggedDocument`-compatible objects.

You should step through working examples in the gensim docs/tutorial-notebooks to get an idea of how things are supposed to work. See for example:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb